# Console log gives null in object header while there is a value in the property

Tags: javascript

I don't know if there is a better way to explain this, but when i do a `console.log` (ie `console.log(balanceSheetCubes.cubes()[0])`  of a javascript object created by a library i use in my web application i got the following output in Chrome Dev Tools

```
Object {id: "8ef9b8dd-044b-8d16-a4a2-306c83b3963c", def: Object, status: 0, data: null, qId: null}
data: Object
def: Object
id: "8ef9b8dd-044b-8d16-a4a2-306c83b3963c"
qId: "MU65"
status: 0
```

Like you can see in the object header `Object {id: "8ef9b8dd-044b-8d16-a4a2-306c83b3963c", def: Object, status: 0, data: null, qId: null}` **qId= null** but if i collapse that object by clicking the arrow before the word `Object` there is definitely a value assigned to the property **qId: "MU65**

When i want to assign this `qId` property to a variable with ie:

```
var tempCube = balanceSheetCubes.cubes()[0];
var firstCube = tempCube.qId;
```

I got `null` returned.

Why does this happen? Anyone that can help me?

Comment: This is very likely due to a change in the value that happens between when you pass the object to `console.log` and when you open the object for visual inspection in the console.

Comment: We need more context here. But sounds like some sort of asynchronous option.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` shows current state of object. So when you are passing that object to `console.log` it might have qId, but later it changes to null.
Try using `console.dir` and see what you get.

Comment: `console.dir`gives me a qId that has this value and not the `null`. I could give you the library i use it is called senseUtils.js

Comment: try assinging `var qId = tempCube.qId;` and log that variable qId. By not logging object property, but value directly it should show value in that point of time when console loge was called.

Answer (score 0):

If your console is displaying null when you attempt to log an element ie console.log(document.getElementById(“”))… then it’s best practice to go through your html file and make sure your  tag is at the buttom of your  tag….